# How to get rid of \r\n from a string?

Tags: jython, jython-2.7

I recently had to upgrade to `Jython 2.7.2`. I send in a Java map instance into my python script.

Previously my python script would print out the key, value in the map as in the below format

```
message: Community: public
```

This same string now appears as

```
u'message': u'Community:\t\tpublic\r
```

I managed to get rid of the `u'` prefix by doing the following

```
encode(encoding = 'UTF-8', errors = 'strict')
```

But am still left with the `\t\r` in the string

```
'message': 'Community:\t\tpublic\r
```

and it feels very clumsy to manually remove these from the string. Is there any good utility method that would help me to preserve the pre `2.7.7` handling of strings?

Comment: Well to follow the clumsy way you could use replace to get rid of \t and \r. However I do not know Jython enough to fix the root cause, this is also the reason why this is a comment, not an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Normally the character `\r` comes from a windows' file and the easiest way to get rid of them is just use `replace`

```py
mystring = u'asd\r'
mystring = mystring.replace("\r", "")
print(repr(mystring))
```

Gives the output:

```
u'asd'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `toString()` method and then replace the unwanted characters?

Sample code:

```
import java.util.HashMap as HashMap
import re


def test_2():
    my_map = HashMap()
    inner_map = HashMap()
    inner_map.put("community", "public")
    my_map.put("message", inner_map)

    print re.sub(r"[{}]*", "", my_map.toString()).replace("=", ": ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_2()
```

Output:

```
message: community: public
```